# Service Solicitation Advertising Data in Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

My question is about Service Solicitation.
In BLE, there is an option of Service Solicitation in Advertising Data Packet.
What is the meaning of Service Solicitation??
In which situation, we include Service Solicitation Data in Advertising Packet?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to **re-organize** your questions and you can refer to "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 7):

The idea is that when a device scans an advertising device, having a particular solicited service uuid in its advertising data, and the scanner itself has that service in its own gatt db, the scanner should connect to that device.

So basically it means that it advertises "anyone having this service, please connect to me".

But I don't think anyone actually uses this feature...

Comment: Thanks Emil for your explanation.

Now i understood what is Service Solicitation & where it is used.

Comment: @Emil Im going to use it now that you explained it :)